# prefiltering of predictors using cforest for ctree possible?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, importance, party

I am attempting to create a conditional inference tree using the R-package `ctree` for a dataset. Unfortunately, the sample size is small and the effects are weak. As the analysis is discovery-driven, we are rather liberal with the significance level and are not doing a Bonferroni correction within ctree. However, this approach increases the risk of false positives.

I would like to know whether it would make sense to perform forward selection/prefiltering of predictors before creating the final ctree model. Is this a valid approach or are there other methods to obtain a robust decision tree? maybe you also know some papers where they tried similar strategies.

example R code:

```
# Load packages and data
library(partykit)
library(mlbench)
data("BostonHousing2")

# Set random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create a subset of samples and predictors for speed reasons
pred_df <- BostonHousing2[1:200, !(colnames(BostonHousing2) %in% c("town", "chas", "cmedv"))]

# Build cforest model and get variable importance
cforest_model <- cforest(medv ~ ., data = pred_df, ntree = 50)
predictor_varimp <- varimp(cforest_model, conditional = TRUE)

# Check variable importance and set an arbitrary threshold (will be decided otherwise)
dotchart(sort(predictor_varimp))
abline(v = 1, col = 'red')
sig_predictors <- names(predictor_varimp[predictor_varimp > 1])

# Create ctree with only important predictors
current_ctree_control <- ctree_control(testtype = "Univariate", minbucket = 20, alpha = 0.05)
ctree_model_varimp <- ctree(medv ~ ., data = pred_df[, c('medv', sig_predictors)], control = current_ctree_control)
plot(ctree_model_varimp)

# Create ctree with all predictors
ctree_model <- ctree(medv ~ ., data = pred_df, control = current_ctree_control)
plot(ctree_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do use an approach like the one you outline but I don't think it is particularly appealing. The interpretation of the resulting tree would be rather unclear.

If your data set is rather small anyway and you want to find a small robust tree capturing its structure, I would recommend attempting to find a "globally optimal" tree (rather than using the locally optimal forward search). One way to do this in R is to use the [evtree](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=evtree) package by [Grubinger *et al.* (2014, JSS)](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v061.i01). Using a sufficiently large number of trees (`ntrees`) should give you a stable and robust result on a small data set.

Alternatively, if you are really after using a forest and understanding its structure, you might try the [C443](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=C443) package by [Sies & Van Mechelen (2020, JoC)](https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs00357-019-09350-4).